# Eliminate the rows that becomes same after swapping as in original table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table which contains data as follows:

```
create table journey(
Src varchar(255), Dest varchar(255))

insert into journey values('Jaipur', 'Mumbai'), ('Mumbai', 'Jaipur'), ('Kolkata', 'Bangalore'), ('Bangalore', 'Indore'), ('Indore', 'Lucknow'), ('Lucknow', 'Indore')
```

I want a table which do not have Mumbai--->Jaipur as it is present already before being swapped. Similarly, Lucknow--->Indore is not required. All other entries must come as it is which is there in the existing table.

Can any body help.

**Note: Table must not have any id or S.No. in the table.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `view` or use `select` statement with `not exists` to prevent duplicate journey :

```
select j.*
from journey  j
where not exists (select 1 
                  from journey j1 
                  where j1.src = j.dest and j1.dest = j.src and 
                        j1.src < j.src and j1.dest > j.dest
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use computed columns and a unique index:

```
alter table journey add least_src_dest as (case when src < dest then src else dest end) persisted;

alter table journey add greatest_src_dest as (case when src < dest then dest else src end) persisted;

create unique index unq_journey_least_greatest on journey(least_src_dest, greatest_src_desc);
```

Another method is to insist on an ordering between `src` and `dest` using a `check` constraint and then add a unique constraint:

```
alter table journey check (src < dest);

create unique index unq_journey_src_desc on journey(src,desc);
```

Note:  This only allows the pair to be inserted as "Jaipur"/"Mumbai".

Also, column names like `src` and `dest` are not consistent with this constraint.  A plane route from Jaipur to Mumbai is quite different from a route from Mumbai to Jaipur.  These should probably be named something like `location1` and `location2`.